# How to fix the attribute is not declared while performing xml validation

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd

How to resolve "The 'Level' attribute is not declared." error with next xml file:

```
<Settings xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
          xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Settings.xsd"> 
  <ItemId Level="Guest" xsi:type="xs:string">Tech Support</ItemId>
  <ItemType Level="Administrator" xsi:type="xs:int">1</ItemType>
  <ItemShift Level="User" xsi:type="xs:time">07:00:00</ItemShift>   
</Settings>
```

and schema file:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified" >
    <xs:simpleType name="typeLevels">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="Administrator" />
            <xs:enumeration value="User" />
            <xs:enumeration value="Guest" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:attribute name="Level" type="typeLevels" />
    <xs:complexType name="MySettings">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:any processContents="lax" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:anyAttribute namespace="##targetNamespace" processContents="lax"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="Settings" type="MySettings"/>
</xs:schema>
```

Removing `xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"` namespace from xml file fixes issue with `Level` attribute, but creates "The attribute 'type' has an invalid value 'xs:string' according to its schema type 'QName' - 'xs' is an undeclared prefix." error.
Validation executed with next code:

```
void Validate(string xml, string xsd)
{
    var schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();
    schemaSet.Add(null, xsd);
    var settings = new XmlReaderSettings { 
        ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema };
    settings.Schemas = schemaSet;
    settings.ValidationFlags |=
        XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation |
        XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessInlineSchema;
    settings.ValidationEventHandler += (sender, e) => {
        switch (e.Severity){
            case XmlSeverityType.Error:
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                break;
        }};
    using (XmlReader validator = XmlReader.Create(xml, settings)) {
        while (validator.Read()) ;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have reopened this because I can't see how either of the referenced articles answers the question.

Comment: What is `XmlXsdResolver`?

Comment: I have removed `XmlXsdResolver` from Validate function as it is not related to this issue

Answer (score 1):

I think what is happening here is as follows:

- The ItemId element matches the lax element wildcard `xs:any`
- There is no element declaration for the element, so it is validated using its xsi:type attribute
- The xsi:type attribute says the element must be of type `xs:string`. But `xs:string` is a simple type, and simple types do not permit attributes.

I would need to check the spec to be sure of this, but I think that's the explanation.

The fact that type `MySettings` has an attribute wildcard makes no difference because this type is not being used to validate the element in question. And the fact that there is a global attribute declaration for attributes named `Level` also makes no difference because there is no element declaration that references this attribute declaration.

How to fix it? Hard to say without knowing what your actual validation rules are (it's hard to reverse engineer a spec from incorrect code). If you want to allow the Settings element to have children with any name and with a Level attribute that meets certain conditions, I don't think that's achievable in XSD 1.0 - there's no way with an element wildcard of constraining the types of the elements that it matches, unfortunately.

Comment: Yes you are right, the specs are to "allow the Settings element to have children with any name and with a Level attribute that meets certain conditions". Currently validation is filtering such errors based on regex, but it does not work with switching system language. The other issue is that Level attribute value is not validated against schema.